# Facebook Marketing API filter ads by insight spend amount

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

Im trying to get the ads of an account like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_id?fields=account_id,name,ads{id,name,insights{spend}}
```

However there are thousands of ads, so I would like to filter them by `spend` **(only get the ads that have spend > 0)**. So I tried this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_id?fields=account_id,name,ads{id,name,insights{spend}}&filtering=[{field: "ads.insights.spend",operator:"GREATER_THAN", value:'0'}]
```

BUT doesn't seem to work. So I also tried this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/act_id/ads?fields=id,name,insights{spend}&filtering=[{field: "insights.spend",operator:"GREATER_THAN", value:'0'}
```

BUT I get this error:

```
(#100) Filtering field 'insights.spend' with operation 'greater_than' is not supported"
```

So is there a way to accomplish this?

Im also using the javascript sdk so if theres a way to do it with that please share!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I finally figure out how to do this, hope this helps somebody:

```
act_ID/ads?fields=fields=id,name,insights{spend}&filtering=[{'field':'spend','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'0'}]
```

but that is not really useful without some filtering: you should filter the insights & the ads like this

```
act_ID/ads?fields=fields=id,name,insights.time_range({'since':'YYYY-MM-DD','until':'YYYY-MM-DD'}){spend}&filtering=[{'field':'spend','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'0'}]&time_range={'since':'YYYY-MM-DD','until':'YYYY-MM-DD'}
```